# Trigger-run a Google Sheets script to fetch URL data from Yahoo Finance in batches

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Prelude - this is quite a long post but mostly because of the many pictures to clarify my issue :)

I have been pulling company data from Yahoo! Finance, first for only a few stocks, but currently for hundred of stocks (and soon to be thousands). I am currently pulling this data live, with one urlFetch per stock ticker each time I load the spreadsheet. This presents three problems:

- It takes a long time for the sheet to load as it is making hundreds of requests to Yahoo!
- I regularly get rate limited on Google side (max. 20k url fetches per day)
- I might get rate-limited on Yahoo! Finance side

I am therefore looking for a better way:

- Instead of calling Yahoo for each ticker each time the spreadsheet loads, I will run a google script that fetches data for each ticker once per day

Consider the following simplified example sheet (tab `db`):

[image]

The current script reads:

```
function trigger() {
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db');
  const tickers = db.getRange('A2:A' + db.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();

  for (var row = 0; row < tickers.length; row++) {
    var data = yahoo(tickers[row]);
    db.getRange(row + 2, 2, 1, 3).setValues(data);
  }
}

function yahoo(ticker) {
  return [ticker, "SOME", "DATA", "MORE"]
}
```

Please note that for purposes of testing, `yahoo()` is simply returning an array. In reality, the `yahoo()` function pulls `JSON` data from Yahoo! After running the script, the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

So far so good. But if the list is not 3 but 5000 tickers long, running the script as-is will get me rate-limited quickly (or waiting very long for the spreadsheet to load). Therefore, I thought about the following:

- Each time the script is run, it will only pull data for 5 tickers. The script will be run once per minute. (5 tickers and per minute for the purposes of this thread)
- The script will keep track of the last time it downloaded data for each ticker

Assume that the list currently looks like this:

[image]

Assume that today is May 31st, and the script is run:

[image]

Starting at the top of the lists, the script should want to update 5 tickers that have not yet been updated today:

- `BLK` in row 2 has already been updated today, so it is ommitted
- `AAPL` was last updated yesterday, so it is the first ticker that gets queried with Yahoo!
- etc.

Now row 2 to 9 have updated data. The second time the script is run, it should update the next five. Again starting from the top, looking for the first 5 tickers either (1) without a "last run" date or (2) a run date before today:

[image]

As you can see, lines 11 to 15 are now updated too. `TSLA` was skipped, because (for whatever reason), it already was updated today.

Here is the same list again, just with 2 more tickers. If the script is run a few times on june 1st, the result will be like this:

[image]

- 3 batches of 5 tickers
- one batch of 2 tickers

This works great if the Yahoo! Finance service would always return data for each ticker. However, it will not. For example because:

- it has no data for a certain ticker
- the request is timing out

I believe I need a solution to keep track of errors while downloading data. Assume the script is run again a few times (triggered by a once-per-minute trigger in Google script) on june 2nd, and have the following result:

[image]

We see two tickers (`JPM` and `ORCL`) where data could not be updated. Both are marked in the error column, filled by the script-to-be.

Let's assume we run the script again on june 3rd. On this day, `JPM` data is downloading perfectly, but `ORCL` again is generating an error. Yahoo! didn't return any data. The `error` column is updated to `2`.

[image]

If a ticker did not get data returned for 2 attempts in a row (`error = 2`), it should be forever skipped. I will fill it in manually at some point, or look into whether I have typed in a non-existing ticker for instance.

Keeping that of errornous downloads prevents the script from getting stuck. Without it, if there are 5 tickers at the top of the list that keep throwing errors, the script will never go past beyond those 5. It will try to attempt to download data from Yahoo over and over for these tickers.

In this last picture, we see the result of the script being run on june 4th. I have colored again the batches (5 tickers) that were updated per run/ minute.

[image]

I tried my best to explain how I am thinking of building a error-proof downloading from Yahoo! Finance. In the rest of my spreadsheet, whenever I need metadata from company, I can simple take it from this `db` tab instead of querying Yahoo! over and over.

My issue is that my scripting skills are limited. I am not overseeing how to start building this. Could someone please:

- Give me a start with (pseudo) code OR
- Give feedback on my thoughts. Am I missing something here that could present a problem?

PS. I understand that I am still making 5 urlfetches per time the script is run. It was suggested to me that I should batch these 5 together (which would prevent me from being rate limited at least on Google's side). This is a great idea, but I found it difficult to understand how it works, so I would rather first have a script that works and that I can follow. In a later stage, I will definitely upgrade / make it more efficient :)

If you've read all the way until here, thank you so much. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[EDIT1]: in reality, `yahoo()` looks like this:

```
function yahoo(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [[fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}
```

[EDIT2] [Example spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yYAOUuGHT5b-uHwcXXcCda2j_Z7kjRFGBp9MFQwa8g/edit?usp=sharing).

[EDIT3] Current scripts in example spreadsheet:

```
function trigger() {
  const max = 5; // From your question, maximum execution of "yahoo" is 5.

  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd");
  const db    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db');
  const range = db.getRange('A2:F' + db.getLastRow());
  
  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    const [ticker, b, c, d, e, f] = r;
    if (o.c < max && (e.toString() == "" || Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd") != today)) {
      try {
        o.c++;
        o.values.push([...yahoo(ticker), today, null]);
      } catch (_) {
        o.values.push([ticker, b, c, d, today, ["", "0"].includes(f.toString()) ? 1 : f + 1]);
      }
    } else {
      o.values.push(r);
    }
    return o;
  }, { values: [], c: 0 });
  range.setValues(values);
}


function yahoo(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [[ticker, fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}
```

[EDIT4] Result after running script for 4 times:

[image]

[EDIT5] Existing data in columns `B` and `C` gets overwritten

Before running the script:
[image]

After running the script:
[image]

[EDIT6]:

```
function trigger() {
  const max = 5; // From your question, maximum execution of "yahoo" is 5.

  const todayObj = new Date();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(todayObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd");
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db2');
  const range = db.getRange('A2:AO' + db.getLastRow());

  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((zo, zr) => {
    const [ticker, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, r, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ag, ah, ai, aj, ak, al, am, an, ao] = zr;
    if (zo.zc < max && (g.toString() == "" || Utilities.formatDate(an, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd") != today)) {
      try {
        zo.zc++;
        zo.values.push([ticker, b, c, ...yahoo(ticker), todayObj, null]);
      } catch (_) {
        zo.values.push([ticker, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, r, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ag, ah, ai, aj, ak, al, am, todayObj, ["", "0"].includes(an.toString()) ? 1 : ao + 1]);
      }
    } else {
      zo.values.push(zr);
    }
    return zo;
  }, { values: [], zc: 0 });
  range.setValues(values);
}


function yahoo(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=summaryDetail,financialData,defaultKeyStatistics';

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  // misc
  let marketCap               = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.marketCap?.raw                       || '-';
  let dividendRate            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.dividendRate?.raw                    || '-';
  let dividendYield           = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.dividendYield?.raw                   || '-';
  let payoutRatio             = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.payoutRatio?.raw                     || '-';
  let fiveYAvgDivYield        = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.fiveYearAvgDividendYield?.raw        || '-';
  let insidersPercentHeld     = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.majorHoldersBreakdown?.insidersPercentHeld?.raw     || '-';
  let institutionsPercentHeld = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.majorHoldersBreakdown?.institutionsPercentHeld?.raw || '-';
  
  // dates
  let earningsDate            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.calendarEvents?.earnings?.earningsDate[0]?.raw      || '-';
  let exDividendDate          = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.calendarEvents?.exDividendDate?.raw                 || '-';
  let dividendDate            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.calendarEvents?.dividendDate?.raw                   || '-';

  // earnings
  let totalRevenue            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.totalRevenue?.raw                    || '-';
  let revenueGrowth           = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.revenueGrowth?.raw                   || '-';
  let revenuePerShare         = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.revenuePerShare?.raw                 || '-';
  let ebitda                  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.ebitda?.raw                          || '-';
  let grossProfits            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.grossProfits?.raw                    || '-';
  let earningsGrowth          = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.earningsGrowth?.raw                  || '-';
  let grossMargins            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.grossMargins?.raw                    || '-';
  let ebitdaMargins           = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.ebitdaMargins?.raw                   || '-';
  let operatingMargins        = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.operatingMargins?.raw                || '-';
  let profitMargins           = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.profitMargins?.raw                   || '-';

  // cash
  let totalCash               = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.totalCash?.raw                       || '-';
  let freeCashflow            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.freeCashflow?.raw                    || '-';
  let opCashflow              = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.operatingCashflow?.raw               || '-';
  let cashPerShare            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.totalCashPerShare?.raw               || '-';

  // debt
  let totalDebt               = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.totalDebt?.raw                       || '-';
  let debtToEquity            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.debtToEquity?.raw                    || '-';

  // ratios
  let quickRatio              = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.quickRatio?.raw                      || '-';
  let currentRatio            = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.currentRatio?.raw                    || '-';
  let trailingEps             = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.trailingEps?.raw              || '-';
  let forwardEps              = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.forwardEps?.raw               || '-';
  let pegRatio                = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.pegRatio?.raw                 || '-';
  let priceToBook             = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.priceToBook?.raw              || '-';
  let returnOnAssets          = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.returnOnAssets?.raw                  || '-';
  let returnOnEquity          = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.returnOnEquity?.raw                  || '-';

  let enterpriseValue         = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.enterpriseValue?.raw          || '-';
  let bookValue               = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.defaultKeyStatistics?.bookValue?.raw                || '-';

  return [
    marketCap, dividendRate, dividendYield, payoutRatio, fiveYAvgDivYield, insidersPercentHeld, institutionsPercentHeld,
    earningsDate, exDividendDate, dividendDate,
    totalRevenue, revenueGrowth, revenuePerShare, ebitda, grossProfits, earningsGrowth, grossMargins, ebitdaMargins, operatingMargins, profitMargins,
    totalCash, freeCashflow, opCashflow, cashPerShare,
    totalDebt, debtToEquity,
    quickRatio, currentRatio, trailingEps, forwardEps, pegRatio, priceToBook, returnOnAssets, returnOnEquity,
    enterpriseValue, bookValue
  ];
}
```

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I have added the actual `yahoo()` function to the opening post, if this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- By retrieving the values from column "A", you want to run the function `yahoo`, and want to update the columns "B" to "F".

  - By checking the date of the column "E", you want to execute the function of `yahoo`.

    - From your question and showing images, your values of column "E" is the date object. And, you want to check the year, month and day.
  - In this case, you want to execute the function of `yahoo` only 5 times every running.
  - When an error occurs from `yahoo`, you want to count up the column "F". When no error occurs, you want to set `null` to the column "F".
- You want to execute the script by the time-driven trigger.

  - You can install the time-driven trigger by yourself.

When I saw your script, the script for achieving the above goal is not included. And, `setValues` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.

So, in your situation, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This script can be directly run with the script editor. So, before you run this script using the time-driven trigger, I would like to recommend testing this script.

After you tested this script and could confirm the output situation, please install the time-driven trigger to the function. By this, when you install the time-driven trigger to this function, the script is run by the trigger.

```js
function trigger() {
  const max = 5; // From your question, maximum execution of "yahoo" is 5.

  const todayObj = new Date();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(todayObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd");
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = db.getRange('A2:F' + db.getLastRow());

  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    const [ticker, b, c, d, e, f] = r;
    if (o.c < max && (e.toString() == "" || Utilities.formatDate(e, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd") != today)) {
      try {
        o.c++;
        o.values.push([...yahoo(ticker), todayObj, null]);
      } catch (_) {
        o.values.push([ticker, b, c, d, todayObj, ["", "0"].includes(f.toString()) ? 1 : f + 1]);
      }
    } else {
      o.values.push(r);
    }
    return o;
  }, { values: [], c: 0 });
  range.setValues(values);
}


function yahoo(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [ticker, fwdPE, sector, mktCap];
}
```

- When this script is run, I thought that your above goal might be able to be achieved. So,
- From your actual `yahoo`, the returned value is different from your 1st script. So, I also modified it.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot imagine the actual script of `yahoo(ticker)`. So, in order to check the error, I used try-catch. **In this case, it supposes that when the values are not retrieved, an error occurs in `yahoo(ticker)`. Please be careful about this.**
- I cannot understand your actual script of `yahoo(ticker)`. So, please be careful about this.
- From your question and showing images, I understood that you wanted to check the year, month and day. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

From your following additional question,

> also, I have added to the example sheet a second tab (db2) if I could ask you to have a brief look. Here, I have added 2 columns in between ticker and the rest of the data that yahoo() is returning. Assume that I want to fill in other data here. Would it be possible to adjust your script so that it leaves these columns alone, so only works on columns A and D to H?

I understood that you want to add the empty 2 columns "B" and "C" to the result array. In this case, please test the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function trigger() {
  const max = 5; // From your question, maximum execution of "yahoo" is 5.

  const todayObj = new Date();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(todayObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd");
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db2');
  const range = db.getRange('A2:H' + db.getLastRow());

  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    const [ticker, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] = r;
    if (o.c < max && (g.toString() == "" || Utilities.formatDate(g, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd") != today)) {
      try {
        o.c++;
        o.values.push([ticker, b, c, ...yahoo(ticker), todayObj, null]);
      } catch (_) {
        o.values.push([ticker, b, c, d, e, f, todayObj, ["", "0"].includes(f.toString()) ? 1 : h + 1]);
      }
    } else {
      o.values.push(r);
    }
    return o;
  }, { values: [], c: 0 });
  range.setValues(values);
}


function yahoo(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [fwdPE, sector, mktCap];
}
```

- Both `trigger` and `yahoo` functions were modified. And, in order to use your 2nd tab of your provided Spreadsheet, the sheet name was also changed to `db2`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hi! I have added the real `yahoo()` to the opening post. Does that help you to better imagine? Please not that it does not yet have error handling, but it indeed will.

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying and adding the script of `yahoo`. In this case, for example, when the invalid value is returned, I think that an error occurs even when `muteHttpExceptions: true` is used. So, I think that try-catch can be used. But, when I saw your added script of `yahoo`, it seems that the returned value is different. Your initial script, `return [ticker, "SOME", "DATA", "MORE"]` is return. But, your actual `yahoo` returns `return [[fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];`. Please modify this for the returned value of 1st script. By this, I think that my sample script works. Can you test it?

Comment: @Pr0no If you cannot understand my comment, please modify your actual `yahoo` as follows. From `return [[fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];` to `return [ticker, fwdPE, sector, mktCap];`, and test it again.

Comment: thanks, I will try. One question however. I made a list (in `db` spreadsheet) of 10 tickers. When running your script, I would have expected it to fill values for only the first 5, but it filled values for all 10. Am I misunderstanding how your script works? Because I do see a `max = 5` definition. Is this because you are batching `yahoo` commands? Under what circumstances would your script not execute the full list of tickers?

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. About `owever. I made a list (in db spreadsheet) of 10 tickers. When running your script, I would have expected it to fill values for only the first 5, but it filled values for all 10. Am I misunderstanding how your script works?`, in this case, I think that it is required to confirm your tested Spreadsheet. So, can you provide your tested sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: sure! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yYAOUuGHT5b-uHwcXXcCda2j_Z7kjRFGBp9MFQwa8g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Pr0no From your provided sample Spreadsheet, I modified the scripts of both `trigger` and `yahoo`.  Could you please confirm it? When you test this script, please use your provided Spreadsheet.

Comment: when I use the provided example sheet and run your function manually, I get an error `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 6.`. Do you not get the same? The scripts for me look like how they are on SO (in other words, I do not see any changes you might have made in the script on Google Sheets).

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. About `when I use the provided example sheet and run your function manually, I get an error Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 6.. Do you not get the same?`, I have no error. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your situation. can you provide your latest Spreadsheet including the latest script for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your effort! It is greatly appreciated. Please see the opening post under [EDIT3]. I have copied the scripts there as they are now in my sample Google Sheet. Does that help?

Comment: @Pr0no If your added "[EDIT3] Current scripts in example spreadsheet:" is your latest script, unfortunately, you are not using my proposed script. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. So, could you please confirm my proposed script again? For example, please reopen this question by the browser and confirm my proposed script again? I modified both `trigger` and`yahoo`.

Comment: apologies, I indeed was using an older version. Please refer to [EDIT4] in the opening post for the result after running the script 4 times. One question: it correctly marked `ZZZZZ` as `error 1`, but then never returned to that ticker to retry. So with your solution, it will mark an error as `1` but then never goes back to that ticker to retry, correct?

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your goal. In your goal, for example, when the script is run today and an error occurs and `1` is put to the column "F". In this case, when you run the script again, you don't want to run the row with `1` of the column "F"? Or, you want to run the row with `1` of the column "F", again? I'm worried thought that here, I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: also, I have added to the example sheet a second tab (`db2`) if I could ask you to have a brief look. Here, I have added 2 columns in between `ticker` and the rest of the data that `yahoo()` is returning. Assume that I want to fill in other data here. Would it be possible to adjust your script so that it leaves these columns alone, so only works on columns A and D to H?

Comment: `Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your goal. In your goal, for example, when the script is run today and an error occurs and 1 is put to the column "F". In this case, when you run the script again, you don't want to run the row with 1 of the column "F"?` -- my mistake, you have understood correctly. The script works as intended. It works really great acually. I manually changed one of the dates to yesterday to see what it would do and it filled that one ticker with changed date, and 4 more tickers on the bottom of the list :)

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Pr0no About your new question of `Would it be possible to adjust your script so that it leaves these columns alone, so only works on columns A and D to H?`, I would like to support you. But, this is a different question from your this question. First, I would like to recommend to propose resolving your initial question. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed different from my original question. I only thought about this change later. You have indeed resolved the original question, many thanks! Would it be possible for you to make this change in the code also?

Comment: `Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about it?` -- yes, it is resolved :)

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Would it be possible for you to make this change in the code also?`, in this case, you want to add the empty 2 columns "B" and "C" to the result array. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @Pr0no I added one more sample script for your additional question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: this is brilliant, thanks. It works exactly as intended now :) If I ever need more scripts, could I also hire you for a reasonable fee or do you only provide answers via this forum?

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. I'm glad your additional question was also resolved. About `If I ever need more scripts, could I also hire you for a reasonable fee or do you only provide answers via this forum?`, unfortunately, I cannot directly answer to the specific user using email. But, in this case, I think that there are the following 2 patterns for resolving your issue.

Comment: @Pr0no 1. Ask your issue as a new question to Stackoverflow. In this case, I can also support you. 2. Contact Apps Script consultant list. [Ref](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/5T9Lv8gYtYE/m/aYPRWNCRAQAJ) I believe think that your issue will be able to be resolved by a lot of answerers.

Comment: I just noticed something that does not work as intended in the script. Please see [EDIT5]. What I meant was that columns `B` and `C` might have EXISTING data in it,. The script is currently overwriting this data (because it returns an array with `null, null`) but it should leave it alone (not overwrite. Is it possible to fix this? I am very sorry if I was unclear in the requirement.

Comment: @Pr0no About your new issue, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Could you please take a look at the example Google Sheet again (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yYAOUuGHT5b-uHwcXXcCda2j_Z7kjRFGBp9MFQwa8g/edit#gid=1524664493). I have been trying to expand the data that is being written into the sheet, but now get an error  when trying to run `trigger(): Syntax error: SyntaxError: Identifier 'r' has already been declared line: 10 file: Code.gs`. But I not seen `r` previously being declared anywhere. Can you please have a look? I have also copied the current code into `[EDIT6]` in the opening post. Your help is so appreciated!

Comment: @Pr0no About your new question, I would like to support you. But when I saw your updated question, it is a new situation. In this case, I think that your question has been changed. So, can you post it as a new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued support. I have opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528695/google-script-says-variable-has-been-previously-declared-but-i-do-not-see-where

Comment: @Pr0no Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I noticed that your new question has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.